# Finding pom.xml in current directory using shell script

Tags: shell, unix

I am trying build all maven projects in a sub directory of the current directory. My shell script is saying that pom file is found irrespective whether file is exists or not. I am not sure if I am doing anything wrong. Could someone please help.

My shell script is

```
#!/bin/bash
#############################################################
#Simple script to build all project in the current directory
#############################################################

dirlist=$(find $1 -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d)

for dir in $dirlist
 do 
   (
   cd $dir
   echo "############################################################################"
   echo "inside directory: " $dir
   echo "############################################################################"
   git checkout development
   git pull
   if find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "pom.xml" # <- this is always true#
    then
     echo "========== Pom file exists to going for building ========= "
     mvn clean install -DskipTests=true
    fi
   )
 done
```

Answer (score 1):

The exit status of `find` is 0, even if it doesn't find anything. It's non-zero for cases like a `-delete` of a non-empty directory, for example, but not for not finding anything.

```
$ ls
file1.txt
$ find -name 'file2.txt'
$ echo $?
0
```

You could just check for existence in your condition instead:

```
if [[ -e 'pom.xml' ]]; then
```